# Can't connect IBAction in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I drag from a button on the storyboard to my view controller Swift file, I only get the option to insert an Outlet or Outlet Collection.

Similarly, if I create the IBAction manually and try to connect it to a button on the storyboard, I can't connect the two.

This problem is only appears in one of my projects, but it happens on all the storyboards in my project.

Seems like an Xcode bug, but maybe someone knows of a workaround.

(It's hard to tell, but the element being dragged in the screenshot is a button.)

[image]

Comment: I have very similar issue -------------------------- when i'm **remove a pod** called **'BonMot'** after that 'Action' is showing , **so that's your one of your pod remove one by one and test it.** hope this is helpful. ## Sachithamh ##

Comment: **BonMot** 4.0.2 has been released, which fixed this problem. It's caused by conforming `UIButton` to any protocol in an extension. I've filed a bug against Xcode.

Comment: [Here's the Apple bug](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5006834117115904), in case you want to dupe it. Mine was duped to a much older bug that's still open.

Answer (score 23):

I have very similar issue in my Swift project that was driving me mad.

It turned that's it is the problem of mixing custom protocol adoption in extension of `UIButton` having `@IBInspectable` property. More details below.

I finally found out that's because I have following code in my project:
(copyright goes to Kevin McNeigh: https://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/swift-programming-101-mastering-dynamic-type-ios)

```
protocol DynamicTypeChangeHandler {

    var typeObserver: Bool {get set}
}

extension UIButton: DynamicTypeChangeHandler {
    @IBInspectable var typeObserver: Bool {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If I remove either protocol adoption from the extension or @IBInspectable keyword, I can again setup actions in Interface Builder. Sheer lunacy. Xcode <3

Comment: Did anyone work out a better fix for this? I'm having the same issue but this is ridiculous! Hoping its fixed in Xcode 8.

Comment: Same issue here.  I didn't have an `@IBInspectable` property, but extended `UIButton` to conform to a protocol.  Had to remove the extension completely in order to create actions again.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Same for me, no IBInspectable, but had to comment the protocol extension for UIButton, to have IBAction working again. Thanks.

Comment: I had a very similar problem in Xcode 8: `UIButton` would be extended by a protocol without an `@IBInspectable` property. Commenting out the extension (as described in this answer) enabled me to connect the button to its action in the storyboard. I need this extension, so I kept digging a little. Turns out that if you **subclass `UIButton`** and extend the subclass by the protocol, things work as intended.

Comment: _…adding any kind of protocol conformance to UIButton or similar, renders it impossible to drag any actions for those elements inside Interface builder_ https://gist.github.com/Moximillian/5f6d60e2cd1222e557547a42558669ae#gistcomment-1988594

Comment: Xcode 9 beta 3 states it has been fixed in its Release Notes.

Answer (score 8):

You can try to change the `@IBAction`'s argument from `(_ sender: Any)` to `(_ sender: UIButton)` or `(_ sender: AnyObject)`, but manually.

It might work.

Comment: For me, this was necessary when connecting actions from multiple UISwitches to a single IBAction.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Fairly obscure but that worked for me too.

Answer (score 5):

I can't speak to the underlying cause--something always seems to be breaking in XCode, but you can always write your IBAction manually, `@IBAction func(sender: UIButton) { }` in your view/controller and then control-drag from the storyboard element to the action itself. If that doesn't work try linking from the node created by an IBAction in the margin of your code back to the storyboard. This works for me when XCode stops working.

Comment: The `action` keyword in our example is not correct, `@IBAction` already marks this as an action.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you select `Automatic`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This bug is indeed super crazy. I lost hours because of it.
Until now I found 2 reasons, and I'll post here maybe somebody will read and be helpful:

1. If anybody is using **BonMot** pod, this is one possible cause. If you remove it, the **IBAction** will be back.
2. Any extension on **UIButton** or **UIBarButtonItem** can cause this as well. Comment the extension, and the **IBAction** will be back. Happy coding.

---

UPDATE: **BonMot** fixed this issue in **4.0.2**

Answer (score 1):

This apparently is a known issue on the Apple forums, but I don't know if Apple is working on it:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/216258

Here is what I did for a workaround.

1. Go into my Podfile and comment out the pod library (in my case, ReactiveKit Bond) that is doing an extension causing the issue.
2. Do a `pod update` to remove the pod from the project.
3. Go back in and do my IBAction connections in IB like I normally would. Do as many together as possible for efficiency.
4. Finally go back and uncomment your pod library and do another `pod update` to reimport the pods.
5. Test by setting a breakpoint in your new IBAction functions to verify your connections are working.

Comment: Looks like they did not fix it in this week's XCode 8.3 release.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was trying to connect multiple buttons to one `IBAction`, none of the solutions worked until I switched my method signature to specify that the sender was a `UIButton` rather than `Any`

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was a FUIButton (custom from SAP Fiori) causing same issue. No pods or UIButton extension specified in my own code (in addition to SAP UIButton obviously). Cmd + Alt + Shift + K, DerivedData Clean didn't help either.
@IBAction wasn't available in Interface Builder till I changed my Button Class back to simple UIButton.

And... voila! ta-da!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it's 2019 and this problem still happens and if anyone is here still looking for a solution, the only way i could get it to work is to:

- Write your IBAction function in the extension
- In Interface Builder, tap File's owner or the main view
- On the Right toolbar click on the Connections Inspector

[image: List item]

- go down the list and find the IBAction you created, sitting there all alone and not connected to anything
- Click on the empty circle next to it and drag to your sad sad button

[image]

- See that sad button is now happy again and connected to something

Answer (score 0):

If extension is causing the problem, then instead of directly extending UIButton, user typealias e.g, create extension of CustomButton instead of UIButton

```
typealias CustomButton = UIButton
extension CustomButton { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but it was because I was trying to connect an ImageView to an IBAction (forgive me, not sure if my terminology is correct).  I deleted the ImageView object and replaced it with a Button and 
IBAction then became an option rather than just IBOutlet and Outlet Collection.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to delete the UIButton from the .xib file and to add it again. Looks like something strange is happening in the .xib file, readding it should be a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the reason was that I changed the name of my **XViewController** name to **YViewController**, so the **storyboard** still had the same old **XViewController** name in its **Identity Inspector** like this:

[image]

All you have to do is to change the view controller's name to the new one and everything will work again :)

[image]