# Can't add action on UITextfield to view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, ibaction

It was fine til suddenly i can't add action to `UITextfield` on xcode, the view controller's class name on storyboard == the view controller's code, no problem on adding action to UIButton, but UITextField has no action option when ctrl dragging to code :((

I wonder what the hell happened

[image: no Action option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay found the problem,

i used SwiftValidator and this: https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator/blob/43fddfb3851b8edc3b26ec0d49404fa445963483/SwiftValidator/Core/Validatable.swift

the extension somehow fucked XCode and i can't add IBAction for UITextFIeld on interface builder.

similar problem but on UIButton: [Can't connect IBAction in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732903/cant-connect-ibaction-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method  of `UITexFieldDelegate` protocol. This method is called when you tap on the text field

Answer (score -1):

UITextField  does not provide an action. Use UITextFieldDelegate.

Check this link https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate

Comment: i can add IBAction using ctrl-dragging the uitextfield to the code before, and you can see it on the "sent events" in connection inspector: http://i.imgur.com/IWGcdY5.png (i tried creating new project)

but in my current project there's no sent events on the uitextfields